# What does the symbol with the arrow pointing to it mean?

Tags: diagram

I am looking at the moon rover’s schematics and came across this symbol.

I can’t find what it means online.

Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CB means circuit breaker, 5A would be rated current.